# Django Converting to CBV + tests

Tags: python, django, testing, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to test my app. I went over the documentation, and managed to make the test for my URL's and all views but one.

I'm having trouble converting it to a class view and I'm not really sure what kind of tests should I do here ? The documentation explained how it works, but I don't now where to go from here..

Anyone mind helping me out ?

here is the view that I'm trying to convert and test :

```py
def add_comment_to_article(request, pk):
    article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommentForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            comment = form.save(commit=False)
            comment.post = article
            comment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:article', kwargs={"article_id": article.pk}))
    else:
        form = CommentForm()
    return render(request, 'news/add_comment_to_article.html', {'form': form})
```

my urls :

```py
app_name = "news"
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<int:article_id>/', views.article_view, name='article'),
    path('articles/', views.ArticlesView.as_view(), name='articles'),
    path('search/', include('haystack.urls',)),
    path('<int:pk>/comment/', views.CommentCreateView.as_view(), name='add_comment_to_article'),
    #path('articles/<int:category_id>', views.CategoryView.as_view(), name="category")
]
```

my form:

```py
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Comment
        fields = ('author', 'text',)
```

The view is in charge of adding a comment to my Article post.
Thank you !!

Answer (score 1):

So assuming you don't have the `post` field in your `CommentForm`, I'd maybe do something like this:

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic import CreateView

from .models import Comment


class CommentCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Comment
    form_class = CommentForm
    template_name = 'my_template.html'

    def form_valid(self, *args, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, pk=kwargs.get('pk'))
        comment = form.save(commit=False)
        comment.post = article
        comment.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('news:article', kwargs={'article_id': article.pk}))
```

```
# tests.py

from django.tests import TestCase


class CreateCommentViewTestCase(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        # maybe look into factory boy if you haven't already
        self.article = Article.objects.create()

    def test_get(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse('news:add_comment_to_article', kwargs={'article_id': self.article.pk}))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_post(self):
        # populate with form data
        post_data = {'form_field': 'value'}
        original_comment_count = self.article.comment_set.all().count()
        response = self.client.post(reverse('news:add_comment_to_article', kwargs={'article_id': self.article.pk}))
        new_comment_count = self.article.comment_set.all().count()
        self.assertNotEqual(original_comment_count, new_comment_count)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)
```

`django-webtest` is pretty useful for testing CBVs too.

Comment: Thanks for the help ! Had no clue django-webtest even exists, will definately check it out !

I did what you suggested, I can get to the comment "page" but when I actually click add comment I'm supposed to be redirected back to my article page, but instead I got this :
Page not found (404)
Request Method:  POST
Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/2/comment/
Raised by:  news.views.CommentCreateView

I added my urls and form to my original post.

Comment: @Sandi I've updated the tests given your urls, at what point do you get the 404, when it tries to find the article using `get_object_or_404()` or when the page tries to redirect?

Comment: The 404 happens when I try to post a comment on the actual site. Tests give me a bunch of different errors, but that could be related.